# Drawing shapes on avcapture preview layer by extracting frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, avcapturesession

I'm trying to get each frame presented in the AVCapture preview layer, I want to essentially use openCV to detect specific shapes (more specifically circles) and draw them on screen to user. I can't seem to get the correct method to update the preview layer of the screen, instead I am only able to get output frames from a queue which does not do anything to the preview.

Currently using the following method to extract frames from output buffer:

```
    // Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return image;
    }
```

Are there any ways to get each frame sent to be displayed on preview layer? or any other ways to implement hough detection using AVCapture session rather than opencv Cameras? Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To do this the best way is to take each frame from the method:

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer;
```

in this method extract the UIImage and use a wrapper with OpenCV to find houghcircles in each frame. Hough circles will generate coordinates for where the circles are located, if any. I then can use the location of the circles to draw a CAShapeLayer on the view to show the circle. I use the following to draw the circles in the view:

```
circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, radius, radius)] CGPath]];
[self.previewLayer addSublayer:circleLayer];
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
```

We can simply move the circle based on where the houghcircle is detected by the openCV algorithm like this:

```
[circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(x,y)];
```

The parameters for the CGPoint might need to be tweaked based on orientation of the images captured and scaling factors. This solution works!